# How can you check for a #hash in a URL using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor, fragment-identifier

I have some jQuery/JavaScript code that I want to run only when there is a hash (`#`) anchor link in a URL. How can you check for this character using JavaScript? I need a simple catch-all test that would detect URLs like these:

- `example.com/page.html#anchor`
- `example.com/page.html#anotheranchor`

Basically something along the lines of:

```
if (thereIsAHashInTheUrl) {
    do this;
} else {
    do this;
}
```

Answer (score 1634, accepted):

Simple use of [location hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/hash):

```
if(window.location.hash) {
  // Fragment exists
} else {
  // Fragment doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: Additional: the .location object is only available on the current window's URL, you can't do this for an arbitrary URL (e.g. one stored in a string variable)

Comment: Also, location properties like .hash and .query are also available on <a> elements

Comment: `.search` is available on an `<a>`, not `.query`. Sample jQuery: `$("<a/>").attr({ "href": "http://www.somewhere.com/a/b/c.html?qs=1#fragmenttest" })[0]`. `.hash => "#fragmenttest"` and `.search` = `?qs=1`. From there, hit up the [querystring extraction question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript) to get something other than a string.

Comment: Please note that `window.location.hash` is empty if url ends with '#'. It is ok if you are looking for hash, but not if you are checking if the current URL contains a #.

Answer (score 391):

```
  if(window.location.hash) {
      var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1); //Puts hash in variable, and removes the # character
      alert (hash);
      // hash found
  } else {
      // No hash found
  }
```

Answer (score 58):

Put the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (location.href.indexOf("#") != -1) {
        // Your code in here accessing the string like this
        // location.href.substr(location.href.indexOf("#"))
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 45):

If the URI is not the document's location this snippet will do what you want.

```
var url = 'example.com/page.html#anchor',
    hash = url.split('#')[1];

if (hash) {
    alert(hash)
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 30):

Have you tried this?

```js
if (url.indexOf('#') !== -1) {
    // Url contains a #
}
```

(Where `url` is the URL you want to check, obviously.)

Answer (score 19):

```
$('#myanchor').click(function(){
    window.location.hash = "myanchor"; //set hash
    return false; //disables browser anchor jump behavior
});
$(window).bind('hashchange', function () { //detect hash change
    var hash = window.location.hash.slice(1); //hash to string (= "myanchor")
    //do sth here, hell yeah!
});
```

This will solve the problem ;)

Answer (score 17):

```
window.location.hash
```

will return the hash identifier

Answer (score 10):

...or there's a jquery selector:

```
$('a[href^="#"]')
```

Answer (score 7):

You can parse urls using [modern JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL):

```js
var my_url = new URL('http://www.google.sk/foo?boo=123#baz');

my_url.hash; // outputs "#baz"
my_url.pathname; // outputs "/moo"
​my_url.protocol; // "http:"
​my_url.search; // outputs "?doo=123"
```

urls with no hash will return empty string.

Answer (score 6):

Here's what you can do to periodically check for a change of hash, and then call a function to process the hash value.

```
var hash = false; 
checkHash();

function checkHash(){ 
    if(window.location.hash != hash) { 
        hash = window.location.hash; 
        processHash(hash); 
    } t=setTimeout("checkHash()",400); 
}

function processHash(hash){
    alert(hash);
}
```

Comment: thats only nessesary in ie 6 + 7. Al other browsers have included the onhashchange event

Answer (score 5):

```
function getHash() {
  if (window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    if (hash.length === 0) { 
      return false;
    } else { 
      return hash; 
    }
  } else { 
    return false; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Most people are aware of the URL properties in document.location. That's great if you're only interested in the current page. But the question was about being able to parse anchors on a page not the page itself.

What most people seem to miss is that those same URL properties are also available to anchor elements:

```
// To process anchors on click    
jQuery('a').click(function () {
   if (this.hash) {
      // Clicked anchor has a hash
   } else {
      // Clicked anchor does not have a hash
   }
});

// To process anchors without waiting for an event
jQuery('a').each(function () {
   if (this.hash) {
      // Current anchor has a hash
   } else {
      // Current anchor does not have a hash
   }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var requestedHash = ((window.location.hash.substring(1).split("#",1))+"?").split("?",1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Partridge and Gareths comments above are great. They deserve a separate answer. 
Apparently, hash and search properties are available on any html Link object:

```
<a id="test" href="foo.html?bar#quz">test</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
   alert(document.getElementById('test').search); //bar
   alert(document.getElementById('test').hash); //quz
</script>
```

Or

```
<a href="bar.html?foo" onclick="alert(this.search)">SAY FOO</a>
```

Should you need this on a regular string variable and happen to have jQuery around,
this should work:

```
var mylink = "foo.html?bar#quz";

if ($('<a href="'+mylink+'">').get(0).search=='bar')) {
    // do stuff
}
```

(but its maybe a bit overdone .. )

Answer (score 3):

Throwing this in here as a method for abstracting location properties from arbitrary URI-like strings. Although `window.location instanceof Location` is true, any attempt to invoke `Location` will tell you that it's an illegal constructor. You can still get to things like `hash`, `query`, `protocol` etc by setting your string as the `href` property of a DOM anchor element, which will then share all the address properties with `window.location`.

Simplest way of doing this is:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = string;

string.hash;
```

For convenience, I wrote a little library that utilises this to replace the native `Location` constructor with one that will take strings and produce `window.location`-like objects: [Location.js](https://gist.github.com/barneycarroll/5310151)

Answer (score 1):

Usually clicks go first than location changes,
so after a click is a good idea to setTimeOut
to get updated window.location.hash

```
$(".nav").click(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        updatedHash = location.hash
    },100);
});
```

or you can listen location with:

```
window.onhashchange = function(evt){
   updatedHash = "#" + evt.newURL.split("#")[1]
};
```

I wrote a [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/rgarro/Route32) that does something like
what you want to do.

It's a simple anchor router.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple function that returns `true` or `false` (has / doesn't have a hashtag):

```
var urlToCheck = 'http://www.domain.com/#hashtag';

function hasHashtag(url) {
    return (url.indexOf("#") != -1) ? true : false;
}

// Condition
if(hasHashtag(urlToCheck)) {
    // Do something if has
}
else {
    // Do something if doesn't
}
```

Returns `true` in this case.

Based on @jon-skeet's comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way to test this for the current page URL:

```
  function checkHash(){
      return (location.hash ? true : false);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that all of these answers mostly check window.location.hash and make it difficult to write tests.

```
 const hasHash = string => string.includes('#')
```

You can also remove the hash from a url like so:

```
const removeHash = string => {
 const [url] = string.split('#')
 return url
}
```

And finally you can combine the logic together:

```
if(hasHash(url)) {
 url = removeHash(url)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

sometimes you get the full query string such as "#anchorlink?firstname=mark"

this is my script to get the hash value:

```
var hashId = window.location.hash;
hashId = hashId.match(/#[^?&\/]*/g);

returns -> #anchorlink
```

Comment: Not possible as hash is appended after the query string and is never sent to server. The only time hash would appear before query string is when you modified the url by hand.

Comment: yep, but sometimes people send urls on this format. this is just so you can get only the hash value and neglect the others. :)