# How to monitor the changes in the url (Fragment identifier - the anchor portion of a URL )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, uri-fragment

I'm making a website that tend to handle all the request in one page (Ajax).
so i thought that I could trap every user's click on a link and check **IF** it's on my website i do something on **JavaScript** like an ajax request for example, **ELSE** it would open the link like usual!

doing a watch on window.location did not work!
and moreover I don't know if there is anyway to get the url part that is after the # sign.
Note: both GMail, and Facebook does that I guess!, they use something like this:
http://mail.google.com/mail/**#inbox**
http://www.facebook.com/home.php**#/inbox/?ref=mb**

**Kindly Consider:** that I love to use jQuery in my projects, so any solution using it is preferred.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Omar: The part of the URL after # is the `hash'. Edited your question title and tag. :)

Comment: @o.k.w: The part of the URL after # is called 'fragment', not hash.

Comment: @o.k.w Thanks, I'm not a 'Native' English, so feel free to correct it to be more obvious.

Comment: @DrJokepu: You are right! Hash is more of a javascript notation. `Fragment` is the correct term: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another good read: [Restoring Conventional Browser Navigation to AJAX Applications](http://www.devx.com/webdev/Article/35549/1763/page/1)

Excerpt from the article:

> Many developers have adopted AJAX as a
>   way to develop rich web applications
>   that are almost as interactive and
>   responsive as desktop applications.
>   AJAX works by dividing the web UI into
>   different segments. A user can perform
>   an operation on one segment and then
>   start working on other segments
>   without waiting for the first
>   operation to finish.
>
> But AJAX has a major disadvantage; it
>   breaks standard browser behavior, such
>   as Back, Forward, and bookmarking
>   support. Rather than forcing users to
>   adapt to AJAX's shortcomings,
>   developers should make their AJAX
>   applications comply with the
>   traditional web interaction
>   style,.......

Comment: Good information, I always like to seriously consider the Usability in my websites.

Answer (score 4):

Simple:

```
if(window.location.hash) {
  // Fragment exists
} else {
  // Fragment doesn't exist
}
```

Link:
[How can you check for a #hash in a URL using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298503/how-can-you-check-for-a-hash-in-a-url-using-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

The **fragment** part of the URL is used to enable navigation history (back and forward buttons) on AJAX-enabled websites. If you want to "trap" clicks on links, since you're using jQuery anyway, you could just do that:

```
$('a').click(function()
{
   var item = $(this);
   var url = item.attr('href');
   // your logic here
});
```

If you use fragments (window.location.hash) in constellation with AJAX, note that IE6 submits the fragment part of the url in AJAX requests which can lead to very hard-to-debug bugs, so be aware of that.

Answer (score 4):

There's a `hashchange` event dispatched on the window for most recent browsers.

Comment: I'm looking for a backward compatible (like IE6 :( ) solution.
So I'd prefer to monitor the anchor clicks.

Comment: Hmmm, http://plugins.jquery.com/project/hashchange does the trick :). thanks for the keyword `hashchange`

Answer (score 3):

See @Pekka 's link to [How can you check for a #hash in a URL using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298503/how-can-you-check-for-a-hash-in-a-url-using-javascript) to look at the hash.  Just put that function in the callback to [`window.setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval)

Comment: Note: window.setInterval() might kills performance! I prefer to use event handler (specifically jQuery's way)

Comment: If you look at the jquery hashchange - its just a setinterval script on everything but IE8.  Though, it is a nice script.

Comment: Oh!, I think I might dump it for that.

Comment: ... There is no 'hashchange' event on anything but IE8 - hence the setInterval.  setInterval isnt bad as long as the timer isn't horribly low - it runs at the end of the event loop, so all other events happen first.