# Javascript window.location.hash is defined?

Tags: javascript, hash, window, location, defined

Is there some way I can tell whether `window.location.hash` is defined?

If it is set, then I will be getting the value of the variable, and using it to display extra content on the page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you check for a #hash in a URL using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298503/how-can-you-check-for-a-hash-in-a-url-using-javascript)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    // do stuff!
}
```

Comment: just be careful if window.location.hash == '#'; on some browsers it will show up as '#', on others it will show up as ''.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
if(window.location.hash !== '')
{
}
```

Or

```
if(typeof window.location.hash !== 'undefined')
{
    //your code
}
```

Comment: I think Hamish could have the better answer :) But mine might prove useful if your having problems seeing if it is available to use.