# java parse url with hash sign instead of question mark

Tags: java, parsing, url, hash

I would like to parse an url like this one:

```
http://YOUR_URL/#access_token=166942940015970%7C2.sa0&expires_in=64090
```

I need to get the value of access_token and expires.

Normally those url should be with question mark like:

```
http://YOUR_URL/?access_token=166942940015970%7C2.sa0&expires_in=64090
```

Is there any other possibility than regex with java ?

Could someone tell me why oauth2.0 is with hash sign ("#") and not with question mark ("?") ?

Comment: url.substring(url.indexof("="), url.indexof("%")) for access_token and url.substring(url.lastindexof("="), url.length())

Answer (score 3):

The part at the end is an "anchor", and the Java URL class has a method `getRef()` to return that bit. You'd then have to decode the contents yourself, if necessary.

Comment: yeah thanks that was the answer. I did it javascript side with this regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197591/parsing-url-hash-fragment-identifier-with-javascript/4198132#4198132