# how to get url after hash

Tags: php, url, hash

I have a url that looks something like this:

```
zigzagstudio/#!/page_wedding2
```

and I need to take the part of the url after the #. In fact I need to reach to page_wedding2 in order to take the number ad compare it with and id from my database. Is this possible using php? Does anyone have an example of code? I also searched for a solution using javascript but I don't know how to send it to php using javascript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197591/parsing-url-hash-fragment-identifier-with-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$url = "zigzagstudio/#!/page_wedding2";
$pattern = "([\#\!\/]+(.*))";

preg_match($pattern, $url, $string);
$name = $string[1];
echo $name; // prints 'page_wedding2'
```

Comment: but how do I get the url with the hash? because my link so far looks something like this: 127.0.0.1/zigzagstudio/#!/page_wedding2

Comment: You mean with `#!`? replace `$name = $string[1]` with `$name = $string[0]`

Comment: so you are saying that I should put something like this: $url='127.0.0.1/zigzagstudio/#!/page_wedding2'?\

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = 'zigzagstudio/#!/page_wedding2';
echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT);
```

See [parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url)() docs.

Comment: but can I get the url using php?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to read it in JavaScript and then pass it to your PHP.

Read it in Javascript like this:

```
var query = location.href.split('#');
var anchorPart = query[0];
```

Once you have `anchorPart` and parsed relevant information from it, pass it to your PHP - there may be different ways of doing this, depending on your web application.

You could make an [AJAX request to](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) page_wedding2.php and pass it any parsed information in the querystring.  Use the returned HTML string in your own web page.

**Edit:**  To clarify, [the browser doesn't pass the anchor part of the URL to the server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url).

Comment: Not necessary to use JS, possible in PHP in many different ways.

Comment: Please explain - you [can't read the anchor part](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url) of the URL in PHP, and OP is implying that it needs to be sent to the PHP page from the client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) in PHP and [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) in Javascript.

PHP:

```
$str = 'zigzagstudio/#!/page_wedding2';
$array = explode('#', $str);
echo array_pop($array);
```

Javascript:

```
var str = 'zigzagstudio/#!/page_wedding2';
var str_array = str.split('#');
alert(str_array.pop());
```

Comment: but how do I get the url with the hash? because my link so far looks something like this: http://127.0.0.1/zigzagstudio/#!/page_wedding2