# How to get anchor from URL in IE/Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, safari

I have a webpage that uses anchors to navigate menu categories. Basically when a user clicks a link it redirects to the current page where I parse the anchor from the URL using Javascript to determine which page to display. This works perfectly in every browser besides IE8 (and below) and Safari, where the anchor does not show up in the URL at all so it can't be parsed.

Is there a certain way to link to anchors in these browsers?

Here's the code:

HTML

```
<a href="../menu#page1">Page 1</a>
```

Javascript:

```
var url = window.location.href;  
var loc = url.substring(url.indexOf("#")+1);
```

EDIT: code added

Comment: Post the code you're using to do this, otherwise there's not much we can do to help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing URL hash/fragment identifier with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197591/parsing-url-hash-fragment-identifier-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You can use hidden field with value simillar to href of ancher tag.

```
<a href="../blah-blah/my-page.html">
<input type="hidden" name="link-url" value="="../blah-blah/my-page.html"/>
```

The value of your link url will show in the query string as `www.some-site.html?link-url=../blah-blah/my-site.html` somthing like that. Now you can use your javascript logic to extrat that value.