# Replacing all plus symbols in JavaScript String

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace all + symbols in a JavaScript String with a space.
Based on this thread [Fastest method to replace all instances of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116558/fastest-method-to-replace-all-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string) and this thread [How to replace all dots in a string using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390789/how-to-replace-all-points-in-a-string-in-javascript/9918856#9918856)  I do:

```
soql = soql.replace(/+/g, " ");
```

But that gives:

```
SyntaxError: invalid quantifier
```

Any ideas how I do it?

Comment: Mostly likely you are trying to parse some search parameters that came from the URL??  in that case the correct answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/57018898/1812732

Answer (score 12):

You need to escape the `+` since it is a special character in regex meaning "one or more of the previous character."  There is no previous character in `/+/`, so the regex does not compile.

```
soql = soql.replace(/\+/g, " ");
//or
soql = soql.replace(/[+]/g, " ");
```

Comment: It might be beneficial to use `/\++/g` which should help performance a little

Answer (score 5):

Try escaping the `+`:

```
soql = soql.replace(/\+/g, " ");
```

The `+` in a regular expression actually means "one or more of the previous expression (or group)". Escaping it tells that you want a literal plus sign ("+").

More [information on quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) is available if you google it. You might also want to look into the [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565922570.do) book.