# How to parse # in HTTP GET?

Tags: php

I have this software from another programmer who has left the project. Now I have a problem, some of the URLs with GET variables wont work i think it's because of the # so this URL looks like this.

www.domain.com/myvariable1/myvariable-#2

so as you can see the GET variable only parses 'myvariable-' so the #2 is cutted off. I need to have the full 'myvariable-#2'

I have searched google and spent hours to get this resolved. Please help me. Thank you!

---

EDIT:

So I found a solution in doing this. I parse the whole URL using javascript, and from there I can now get the remaining string after the #

Thank you for all the answers. Thanks a lot!

Comment: ...thats not a get variable, its part of the url.  Cant you break the requested url up by its components?

Comment: That's not an URL. It's missing the scheme, a mandatory part of URL.

Comment: If answers have helped you, then please select one as 'Solution'.

Answer (score 11):

The `#` starts a fragment identifier. Fragments are handled client-side, that part of the URI isn't even sent to the server in the first place, so you simply *cannot* handle it there.

Comment: @MichaelT it is another programmer's software. and he left. I am hired to continue what he is doing, unfortunately this is one of his mistakes.

Comment: Jörg is right. Please read [this from Alan Skorkin](http://www.skorks.com/2010/05/what-every-developer-should-know-about-urls/)

Comment: @VinmarkBenedicto: You can pass any character in URL by properly escaping it. In PHP escaping is done using `urlencode`. PHP will automatically decode parameter values for you, but IIRC you have to decode path yourself (using `urldecode`).

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to get the fragment (`#...`) from PHP. It seems as if there is a way to do that with javascript. See [Parsing URL hash/fragment identifier with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197591/parsing-url-hash-fragment-identifier-with-javascript)

Just in case you're on a Unix box: you can run `nc` ([netcat](http://nc110.sourceforge.net/)) from a terminal window like this:

```
$ nc -l 8080
```

which opens a reading connection on port 8080. Now you can connect a browser on this machine to that port and request a URL, such as `http://localhost:8080/foobar/baz.html#abcde`. The output of netcat identifies the URL the server sees:

```
GET /foobar/baz.html HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.69 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

So the requested path is `/foobar/baz.html` without the fragment identifier (`#abcde`).

Comment: And if you're on Windows, you can examine the contents of HTTP requests using tools such as [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) or [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others, in URLs `#` is the separator for the fragment identifier.

If a `#` character is included in the path, then it must be properly encoded: `www.domain.com/myvariable1/myvariable-%232`.

This way, the path as seen by the server will be `myvariable1/myvariable-#2`.