# How do we get window.location.hash from a Next.js application?

Tags: next.js

If we stick `window.location.hash` in `useEffect`, it will always erroneously return '0'. Apparently it has to do with SSR.

I need to reliably be able to get the hash portion of the URL for my project. How should I best go about it?

Comment: just use `next/router` and `router.asPath`

Comment: It seems that [having the hash fragment on `router.asPath` is not intended](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/25202#issuecomment-966658956) and from that thread I gather it might be removed in the future?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Server side code needs to wait until the code is loaded in the browser to use browser APIs.

Vanilla js server-side compatible

```js
const [isMounted, setMounted] = useState(false);
  
useEffect(() => {
 if (isMounted) {
  console.log('hash', window.location.hash);
 } else {
  setMounted(true);
 }
}, [isMounted]);

if(!isMounted) return <>Loading...</>;
```

Using next/router

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const { asPath } = useRouter();

useEffect(()=>{
 const hash = asPath.split('#')[1];
}, [ asPath ]);
```

FYI you're code shouldn't return a zero.  The first culprit that comes to mind is when a shorthand condition is used without an else.

```js
window && window.location.hash
```

this should have an else

```js
(window && window.location.hash) || null
```

or

```js
window && window.location.hash ? window.location.hash : null
```

Comment: the useeffect not update when the url updated.

Comment: It updates when asPath changes

Comment: From what I can see, hashes are not being included in router.asPath

Answer (score 5):

Extending [@Sean W](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68987010/827129)'s answer, if you want to get a specific hash value from a hash key, [you can use URLSearchParams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57018898/827129):

```js
// example path: /#error=unauthorized_client&error_code=401error_description=Something+went+wrong

import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const { asPath } = useRouter();

useEffect(() => {
  const hash = (asPath as string).split("#")[1]; // error=unauthorized_client&error_code=401error_description=Something+went+wrong
  const parsedHash = new URLSearchParams(hash);
  const errorHash = parsedHash.get("error_description"); // Something went wrong
}, []); // `asPath` omitted from dependencies as ESLint states it won't change
```