# Get the full url including hash with content in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get url with content after hash ?

window.location return me url without hash :/

for example:

www.mystore.com#prodid=1

window.location return only  www.mystore.com

Comment: Take a look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298503/how-can-you-check-for-a-hash-in-a-url-using-javascript

Answer (score 33):

```
window.location.hash
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Note the [properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Location#properties) section.

Answer (score 10):

Try `window.location.hash` this will work

Answer (score 3):

this returns just content after hash

```
window.location.hash.substr(1);
```

ex: `www.mystore.com#prodid=1`

this will give us : `prodid=1`

Comment: The question is not asking for _just_ the hash content.

Comment: This extracts what's after the hash buddy.
Begin the extraction at position 1, and extract the rest of the string ;).
but when we use substr(x, y) we extract from x to y.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the hash part you can use : `window.location.hash`

If you want all the url including the hash part, you can use : `window.location.href`

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You have to build it up yourself:

```
// www.mystore.com#prodid=1
var sansProtocol = window.location.hostname 
    + window.location.hash;

// http://www.mystore.com#prodid=1
var full = window.location.protocol 
    + "//" 
    + window.location.hostname 
    + window.location.hash;
```