# Retreive access_token from url string

Tags: php, jquery, regex, url, query-string

I am using google api and in url i am getting like this:

> http://website.com/generate-token/#access_token=ya29.AHES6ZTJwb9lzb0lua81oHa47-8ImcJf-8qE-02kIn8JcgEv&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600

I tried:

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
$url =  "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

But what i got is http://website.com/generate-token/

How can i get either the complete url and use regex to get the access_token or any other way in which i can get it?

Comment: The URL there has no querystring. The values are part of the `fragment` of the URL. ie. the `#` values. You would need to get `window.location.hash` and `split` it twice by `&` and then `=`, and find the key you want to get the value using JS.

Comment: Short answer: you can't. (not without [JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778990/))

Comment: Did you mean to tag jQuery?  I assume (from the above) that you want to do this at the server.

Comment: I need just the access_token from this url, it can be by any method, either by js, jquery, etc.
@RoryMcCrossan can you tell how can i get it via JS?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with it.  If you want to use the value in PHP then you don't want to do it in JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My two cents (since you tagged it with jQuery i suppose Javascript is a valid solution):

```
var url = 'http://website.com/generate-token/
           #access_token=ya29.AHES6ZTJwb9lzb0lua81oHa47-8ImcJf-8qE-
           02kIn8JcgEv&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600';

function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&#]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    return results == null ? "" : 
           decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

alert(getParameterByName('access_token', url));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yejwF/