# Getting a # in URL from angularJS $stateProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, angularjs-routing

I am getting a strange # in the middle of my url for example if I try to go to localhost:8080 where I have my AngularJS app running I am redirected to http://localhost:8080/#/home. I don't understand where this # is coming from but I suspect it has something to do with the URLs I am defining in my $stateProvider.

Here is the $stateProvider code:

```
//STATE HANDLER
//++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
app.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('newAlarm', {
            url: '/newAlarm',
            views: {
                '': {templateUrl: '/templates/newAlarmPage.html'},
                'header@newAlarm':{templateUrl: '/templates/header.html'},
                'newAlarmForm@newAlarm':{templateUrl: '/templates/newAlarmForm.html'}
            },
            controller: 'NewScheduleCtrl'
        })

        //to be changed
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            views: {
                '': {templateUrl: '/templates/homePage.html'},
                'header@home':{templateUrl: '/templates/header.html'}
            },
            controller: ''
        });
    //end of to be changed
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}]);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729580/how-can-i-use-urls-in-a-single-page-application and then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-hashtag-from-angularjs-urls-symbol on how to remove it

Answer (score 2):

From the Wikipedia article on [single page applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application):

> The page does not reload at any point in the process, nor does control transfer to another page, although the location hash can be used to provide the 
>   perception and navigability of separate logical pages in the application

Use of the hash enables angular (and other SPA frameworks) to route urls without reloading the page.

Related questions:

- [How can I use urls in a single page application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729580/how-can-i-use-urls-in-a-single-page-application)
- [Removing the hashtag from angularjs urls symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-hashtag-from-angularjs-urls-symbol)

Comment: So I've read that AngularJS can be used to make more than just single page apps. In the code I posted I am using one AngularJS app to define two completely separate pages/paths. Is that a good practice?

Comment: If they are all part of the same site/app that is fine...single page applications should be driven by user experiences needs. So if it works for your users then it's good, and i can see it working well for pages at the top level of your application that provide hard links (full page refresh) that have sub-sections that behave like single page apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the hash if you want to.

```
app.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider','$locationProvider',
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {

  //ROUTING

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);
```

Then add in your index html file :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>

    //...

    <base href="/">

  </head>
  //...
</html>
```