# JavaScript - if URL doesn't have a #hash?

Tags: javascript, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you check for a #hash in a URL using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298503/how-can-you-check-for-a-hash-in-a-url-using-javascript)

Im using the following to execute some JavaScript if the URL ends with a certain hash tag. How can I crete a similar conditional for if the URL doesnt end in a hash tag? Thanks

```
    if (window.location.href.match('#hash'))
    {
                //do stuff
    }
```

Comment: Similar but none of them answer it exactly. The first answer is almost there but uses an if and else not just an else.

Comment: `if(!window.location.hash) { ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

```
if(window.location.hash) {
  //hash exists
} else {
  //no hash
}
```