# How do I read #2 at the end of a URL?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you check for a #hash in a URL using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298503/how-can-you-check-for-a-hash-in-a-url-using-javascript)

Currently I am generating Urls that look like this:

InspectionPhotos.aspx?inspectionId=10001649#/2

The #2 is for a photogallery plugin, and this would mean go the second photo.

I would like to show a div only if there is a #/[anynumber] but if its just
InspectionPhotos.aspx?inspectionId=10001649
then not show anything.

How could I do this check? Either asp.net on pageload or a client side javascript would be fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this in server side, because the hash is not sent to the server, to get this value with javascript is simple:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
if (hash){
   //use the hash value.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript: `window.location.hash` will comeback with `#/2` from your example.