# Check if no hashtag is present, hashtag undeclared, no hash

Tags: ajax, onload, hashchange

I'm developing this website: 
http://parkoura.tk/a/sandbox/

I am using an ajax navigation. I have a function called ajax() which is supposed to execute at onload. When it does, I would like it to check first if a hashtag is there. If there is no hashtag, the function then should just break and not do anything. If a hashtag is declared, it sends ajax to another php and replaces content inside a div.

It works perfectly besides the onload hash tag checking part. When the site loads up, you can see for a moment that a slider is rendered. Despite the fact that no hashtag is declared, it then still goes on to replace the content.

I have alerts to show how the logic should be working. My logic for the actual checking is this:

```
    <script>
    if (typeof location.hash != 'undefined' || location.hash != '' || location.hash != '#' || location.hash != '#carousel')
    { no hash,things stay the same the function is not executed.
```

full js code:
https://pastee.org/v8cxp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    // Process your ajax call
} else {
    // "no hash,things stay the same the function is not executed. "
}
```

Possible duplicate of : [How can you check for a #hash in a URL using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298503/how-can-you-check-for-a-hash-in-a-url-using-javascript)

Comment: @user1392515 In relation to your code snippet, you can add in the `if` syntax : `&& window.location.hash != '#carousel'`