# How to grab the # using query string ASP

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

So we have a URL. This url looks like: www.test.com/#test

How do I grab the #test using something similar to

```
statereq = request.querystring("state")
```

I need to perform an action based on what # is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. It isn't sent to the server.

Comment: Is there any alternative? As we can not use traditional query strings, ?state=test. etc.

Comment: You *can* grab it via JavaScript so if you can use that you can then get the hash and send it to your server via Ajax.

Comment: I wouldn't have a clue how to do that. Could you assist? Or do I need to create a new question?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298503/how-can-you-check-for-a-hash-in-a-url-using-javascript) for how to get the hash. There are lots of tutorials for how to use ajax in google and probably on stackoverflow.

Comment: I have managed to get the hash and assigned it to a variable. How do I use that value to alter the sql?

Comment: @sep with jQuery use .get("page.asp?hash=" + myJS_var); then just read the querystring parameter in ASP and use in your SQL.