# Showing a div from an off-page link

Tags: jquery, html, show-hide

I have a sub nav which (using the code below) toggles div off/on when the appropriate link is clicked. It works perfect. The only thing is, now I need to link into this page using a hash (pageName.php#div4) and open the div with the id div4 and I'm not having much in the way of luck.

Any ideas on how I might achieve this?

Sub Nav HTML:

```
<div class="subnav">
    <a href="javascript:;" data-target="1" class="showDiv active">Link</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" data-target="2" class="showDiv">Link</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" data-target="3" class="showDiv">Link</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" data-target="4" class="showDiv">Link</a>
</div>
```

Content HTML:

```
<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Content</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Content</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv">Content</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv">Content</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.showDiv').on('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    $('.targetDiv').fadeOut("fast").delay(200);
    $('#div' + $(this).data('target')).fadeIn("slow");
});

$('.showDiv').first().click();
```

Answer (score 0):

> now I need to link into this page and open - say - div #4

If you want to select an element with ID of `4` you can code:

```
$('div#' + $(this).data('target'))
```

or as IDs are unique:

```
$('#' + $(this).data('target'))
```

---

Edit:

```
var $divs = $('div.targetDiv');
$('.showDiv').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // return if the clicked element has active class 
    if ($this.hasClass('active')) return;
    $this.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    $divs.fadeOut("fast", function() {
       $divs.filter('#div' + $this.data('target')).delay(200).fadeIn("slow");
    })
}).first().click();
```

Comment: Thanks Undefined, I think I might have not explained myself very well. I'd like the sub nav show/hide functionality to stay as is it, but allow a link such as /page.php#div4 to hide all but the div with id="div4". I've added the div code to the original question.

Comment: @rrfive You are welcome, okay, so please update the `div #4` part in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [hash component of the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298503/how-can-you-check-for-a-hash-in-a-url-using-javascript) on the page load event. From there, respond as needed.

Something like

```
$(function()
{
    if(window.location.hash)
    {
        $("#" + window.location.hash).click();
    }
});
```