# How to open bootstrap modal as soon as page opens if modal id is present in url #

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Is there any way using which when a user opens a url `http://www.website.com/page/#delete-page` and if that page has a twitter bootstrap modal with same id `delete-page` it should open instantly.

So in theory the user opens the url, The page loads and after its successfully loaded the modal opens (i..e if it exists if not then nothing happens)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What do you need?

1. Get the hash from the URL: [How can you check for a #hash in a URL using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298503/how-can-you-check-for-a-hash-in-a-url-using-javascript)
2. Once you have the hash, simple get the element with the id selector of the hash and then:

   ```
   $(hash).modal('show')
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, it should work.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    if(window.location.href.indexOf('#myModal') != -1) {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  }

});
```

Or

```
$(document).ready(function() {

if(window.location.href==='mysite.com/#myModal'){
 $('#myModal').modal('show');
}

}
```