# Using anchor tag from URL as id in javascript

Tags: javascript, url

I am trying to use anchor tag from URL in a javascript to show/hide a particular div in an html page. Here is an example for the same.

```
<div style="display:none;" id="test_one">Display this box when one</div>
<div style="display:none;" id="test_two">Display this box when two</div>
```

Now, what I want is, when the URL is http://www.example.com/this_page.html#test_one, I want to display first div (with id test_one). Similarly when the URL is http://www.example.com/this_page.html#test_two, I want to display second div (with id test_two).

Can any one please provide me any pointers on this?

Thanks in Advace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for any hash/id pairs:

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    document.getElementById(hash).style.display = "inline";
}
```

Breaking it down:

1. `if(window.location.hash) {` - only do this if there's a hash value at all.
2. `var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);` - put the hash value in a variable, removing the `#` at the beginning (based on @Mark's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298503/how-can-you-check-for-a-hash-in-a-url-using-javascript)).
3. `document.getElementById(hash).style.display = "inline";` - set the element on the page whose `id` is the same as the hash to a visible `display` value.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was useful to me and I am able to do what I wanted. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try in the JS:

```
if(document.URL=' http://www.example.com/this_page.html#test_one')
document.getElementById('test_one').display='inline';

elseif(document.URL=' http://www.example.com/this_page.html#test_two')
document.getElementById('test_two').display='inline';
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look also at `:target` pseudo selector:

```
div:target {
   display: block;
}
```

Although it is not widely supported by browsers you can implement it as a first step of progressive enhancement.

Answer (score 0):

Get URL from the page and hide that particular div only using JavaScript

CSS:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

HTML

```
<div id="test_one" class="hidden"><!-- div content --></div>
<div id="test_two" class="hidden"><!-- div content --></div>
```

and in jQuery

```
 var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '#' );
 var div_name = pathArray[1];
 $(function () {
 if(div_name=="test_one")
 $('#test_one').removeClass('hidden');
 else
 $('#test_two').removeClass('hidden');
 });
```