# alert if anchor has hashtag/url/mail/phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hash

As simple as that, i am using a menu bar with both hash tags and url...

**HTML:-**

```
<ul class="nav">
           <li class="active"><a href="#firstpage">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="demo.html">Demo</a></li>
                <li><a href="#secondpage">second</a></li>
                <li><a href="#thirdpage">third</a></li>
                <li><a href="#fourthpage">fourth</a></li>
                <li><a href="">fifth</a></li>
                <li><a href="mailto:abc@xyz.com">Email</a></li>
                <li><a href="tel:+000">Phone</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">last</a></li>
            </ul>
```

I want to have a code that alerts when clicking on a hash anchor or a url anchor?

Something like this:-

```
if("anchor has a hash") { alert("It is a hash"); }
else if("anchor has a url") { alert("It is a url"); }
else if("anchor has a email") { alert("It is a email"); }
else if("anchor has a phone number") { alert("It is a phone number"); }
else { alert("Its empty") }
```

What i have referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298503/how-can-you-check-for-a-hash-in-a-url-using-javascript) but cant find a exact solution?

Comment: look at [click event handler](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help

```
$(".nav a").on("click", function(event) {
  var href = $(this).attr("href");

  if (href.indexOf("#") !== -1) {
    alert("hashtag");
  }
  else if (href.length > 0) {
    alert("has a url");
  }
  else {
    alert("blank");
  }
});
```

Comment: nope; you're doing it wrong. good luck.

Comment: Next time try asking for what you actually want the first time around. I don't waste my time on on [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341) questions.

Comment: The example you referred will only work if the page is already loaded. Otherwise the answers already given should do the trick.

Comment: i am satisfied with your answer, ofcourse it will help me...