# Jump to section of page regarding to hashtag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hashtag

Here is the thing

I have two div elements which I want only one of them be displayed and the other be hidden based on following situation:

The first div is a intro page with a button to hide first div and show second div.Second div is the main content of the page.

If user comes with a url that has no hashtag the first div will be shown(Intro) but there is possibility that the user comes with a hashtag in url .In this case I want to jump to second div and ignore intro

```
<div id="first-div">
    <!--intro section-->
    <button>Show details</button>
</div>
<div id="second-div" style="display:none">
    <!--Details-->
    <div id="description"></div>
    <div id="comments"></div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('button').on('click',function(){
            $(this).parent().hide();
            $('#second-div').show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

So the question is how can I handle hashtag in url with JQuery?Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298503/how-can-you-check-for-a-hash-in-a-url-using-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [location.hash](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp) property

```
if (window.location.hash == "#notIntro") {
  // do here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to check `location.hash`, it returns you the part of the URL that is after the #.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if (location.hash != '') {
    $('#first-div').show();
    $('#second-div').hide();
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    $('#first-div').hide();
    $('#second-div').show();
} 
else {
    $('#first-div').show();
    $('#second-div').hide();
}
```