# How to replace the URL of current page in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, url, replace, anchor

I have:

**http://www.domain.com/my-page#my-section**

The code should give alert:

**#my-section**

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you check for a #hash in a URL using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298503/how-can-you-check-for-a-hash-in-a-url-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `window.location.hash`

```
alert(window.location.hash);
```