# JavaScript: get and set URL hash parameters?

Tags: javascript

How do you get and set URL hash parameters in pure JavaScript?

For example, I'd like to use parameters like this: `myurl.com/#from=2012-01-05&to=2013-01-01`

And I'd like to be able to get and set the `from` and `to` parameters in the above.

I'm happy to use the HTML5 history API if that's the best way of doing things.

Comment: Where's the URL? The `location` object and `<a>` elements give you this ability automatically.

Comment: liar! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298503/how-can-you-check-for-a-hash-in-a-url-using-javascript

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I wasn't clear. I'll update the question...

Comment: You want query string parameters in the hash? Why? If you're asking how to manipulate the query  parameters, there's no shortage of information on StackOverflow.

Comment: For such, just use [the code to parse the `location.search` query](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2880929/1048572) on `location.hash`

Comment: @cookiemonster I looked but I couldn't find a solution for the problem above.

Comment: @Bergi thanks - that explains how to get parameters, but not how to set them. I'll see if I can adapt it to set them, and if I can then I'll post working code here.

Comment: @cookiemonster ah I see what you're saying: you're saying it makes more sense to use query string parameters, i.e. `?from=X&to=Y`. Yes, that's completely true, thank you.

Comment: If you want to set the values, I assume that means you want to send them to the server. The hash doesn't get sent.

Comment: >  I assume that means you want to send them to the server
Why assume that? We use this kind of thing purely front end to provide a navigable URL that can setup UI elements.

Answer (score 76):

If you want to parse a hash URL:

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);

var result = hash.split('&').reduce(function (res, item) {
    var parts = item.split('=');
    res[parts[0]] = parts[1];
    return res;
}, {});
```

That way, if you have this:
`http://example.com/#from=2012-01-05&to=2013-01-01`

It becomes: `{'from': '2012-01-05', 'to':'2013-01-01'}`

As @Dean Stamler notes in the comments, dont forget the empty starting object. `}, {});`

Now to set a hash URL:

`window.location.hash = "from=2012-01-05&to=2013-01-01";`

Comment: @RickS, result is an array of all the params.  Note that "from" and "to" are multiple params. Please test it out, it works just fine with multiple params.

Comment: @RickS if it's not working for multiple params it's very likely that you haven't included the empty object `{}` as a second argument to the `reduce()` call. This is the initial value of the accumulator.

Comment: A bit confusing to have the intermediate result and the final result share the same variable name IMO

Answer (score 13):

You can set the hash with:

```
window.location.hash = "new value";
```

and (in [newer browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=hash)) listen to changes with:

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function () {
});
```

If you need to support browsers that don't support `"hashchange"` you'll want to use code that other people have written, such as [jquery's history plugin](http://tkyk.github.io/jquery-history-plugin/).

Comment: Which older browsers do not support `location.hash`? (Btw, it's `window.` usually not `document.`)

Comment: `location.hash` is well supported, but not `"hashchange"`. For older versions of IE you need a hack that involves an iframe. See: http://caniuse.com/#search=hashchange

Comment: Yeah, that's what I expected, but your phrasing "*Newer versions of browsers support setting*" is confusing.

Comment: I just want to make it abundantly clear that there compatibility issues.

Answer (score 12):

As for getting parameters... how about this solution:

```
var myUrl = new URL(window.location.href.replace(/#/g,"?"));
var param_value = myUrl.searchParams.get("param_name");
```

Wish u luck!

Comment: It will work properly only if the url doesn't have any query parameters yet (and doesn't contain `?` yet). So for example for this url it will not work: https://stackoverflow.com/?lala=kuku#bebe=nene

Comment: @Alexander You can solve that issue like this `var myUrl = new URL('a://' + window.location.hash.replace(/^#/g,"?"))` (`a://` is just the shortest possible "valid" url)

Answer (score 6):

The other answers don't address the problem

**I got a way easier approach:**

Copy over current hashparameters to a dummy URL as searchParameters. Now you can treat the hash parameters like search-parameters and copy them back afterwards:

Simple function

```javascript
function setOrUpdateHashParameter( hashParameterName, hashParameterValue ) {
    let theURL              = new URL('https://dummy.com');             // create dummy url
    theURL.search           = window.location.hash.substring(1);        // copy current hash-parameters without the '#' AS search-parameters
    theURL.searchParams.set( hashParameterName, hashParameterValue );   // set or update value with the searchParams-API
    window.location.hash    = theURL.searchParams;                      // Write back as hashparameters
}
```

Comment: Be aware, that it is not working in Internet Explorer 11. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 4):

**For Multiple Params:**

```
const href = window.location.href;
const params = href.split('?')[1];

// Be sure url params exist
if (params && params !== '') {
    const result = params.split('&').reduce(function (res, item) {
        const parts = item.split('=');
        res[parts[0]] = parts[1];
        return res;
    }, {});
}
```

Therefore, when `href=https://www.example.net/page.html#/page1?foo=bar&token=123abc` the `result` will evaluate to `{foo: "bar", token: "123abc"}`.

This structure requires that the URL has the question mark `?` before the params, an equal sign `=` between the variable key and value, and a `&` between each key/value pair.

Comment: Hey! I am trying to use your code snippet and it returns only the last hash value in object. Do you know why it can happen? I am using `window.location.hash` and before applying `reduce`, I do this: `decodeURI(window.location.hash).substr(1).split('&')`.

Comment: The example of url I have: `www.example.com#word=foo&word=bar`. Can it be because I have same key (`word`) for parameters?

Comment: @OlgaB using this snippet, you need to use a `?` to split the params from the rest. You can also replace the `?` in `const params` with `#`.

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution

```js
arr = location.search.replace('?', '').split('&').map(x => x.split('=')).map(x => {
    let keyName = x[0];
    let val = x[1];
    let object = {};
    object[keyName] = val;
    return object;
});

obj = {}

arr.forEach(function(x) {
    let key = Object.keys(x)[0];
    obj[key] = x[key];
});

console.log(obj);
```

Basicaly with location.search we obtain the right part of a url, after the path (the query params with).

location.search also returns the '?' character, replace with white space, then split whit '&', map and split with '=', for obtain un array like

```js
[['term', 'hello'], ['lang', 'es']]
```

Then, assemble the object as you wanted

```js
arr = "?safe=active&source=hp&ei=c4Q8XcOPFd3F5OUP7e242Ag&q=hola&oq=hola&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l5j0i131j0l2j0i131j0.1324.1667..1798...1.0..0.264.744.1j3j1......0....1..gws-wiz.....10..35i39.-_FkFlX_Muw&ved=0ahUKEwiDlaTgytXjAhXdIrkGHe02DosQ4dUDCAU&uact=5".replace('?', '').split('&').map(x => x.split('=')).map(x => {
    let keyName = x[0];
    let val = x[1];
    let object = {};
    object[keyName] = val;
    return object;
});

obj = {}

arr.forEach(function(x) {
    let key = Object.keys(x)[0];
    obj[key] = x[key];
});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: You may want to provide more information as to what your solution does.

Comment: thanks @RobRose, i edit the response then. My english is bad, sorry

Answer (score 2):

For get only:

```js
const startingUrl = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699666/javascript-get-and-set-url-hash-parameters#state=XXX&b=YYY'
const myUrl = new URL(startingUrl);
const hash = new URLSearchParams(myUrl.hash.substring(1))
hash.get('state'); // XXX
hash.get('b'); // YYY
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based upon [Maart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53973230/1688518) here is a version which returns the edited URL rather than applying the change to the current window.

```
function setHashParam(url, name, value) {

    // Create URL objects for the url we want to change and a dummy url (requires a polyfill for IE)
    var urlObj = new URL(url);
    var dummyObj = new URL('https://dummy.com');

    // Copy current hash-parameters without the '#' as search-parameters
    dummyObj.search = urlObj.hash.substring(1);

    // Set or update value with the searchParams-API (requires a polyfill for IE)
    dummyObj.searchParams.set(name, value);

    // Write back as hashparameters
    urlObj.hash = dummyObj.searchParams;

    return urlObj.href;
}
```

Note that for this answer (and Maart's) to work in IE they require polyfills for the URL constructor and the search params API.