# parse hash of URL from ajax call jquery

Tags: javascript

let say i have this script.

```
$('body').load('someurl.html#12', function(data){
    // my code to proccess data
});
```

in `someurl.html` how do i get the hash of this URL? in this case should be `#12`. when i try to parse it using `window.location.hash` what i get is the parent URL without hash of course.

Comment: `'someurl.html#12'.split('#')[1]`?

Comment: duplicate of [How can you check for a #hash in a URL using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298503/how-can-you-check-for-a-hash-in-a-url-using-javascript)

Comment: @user3678068 : yes i know how to split the hash, my problem is when i parse the URL inside someurl.html the value is not someurl.html, instead it is index.html

Comment: `window.location` contains the URL of the page that's running the script, not anything that it loads.

Comment: @Barmar : so how do i get the hash inside that loaded file, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

That can be done using jQuery BBQ [Full reference from here](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/)

> **Parsing the query string or fragment from a URL**

```
The jQuery.param.querystring and jQuery.param.fragment methods can be used to return a normalized query string or fragment from the current document or a specified URL. Complete usage information is available in the documentation.

// Return the document query string (similar to location.search, but with
// any leading ? stripped out).
var qs = $.param.querystring();

// Return the document fragment (similar to location.hash, but with any
// leading # stripped out. The result is *not* urldecoded).
var hash = $.param.fragment();

// Parse URL, returning the query string, stripping out the leading ?.
// qs is set to "a=1&b=2&c=3"
var qs = $.param.querystring( "/index.php?a=1&b=2&c=3#hello-world" );

// Parse URL, returning the fragment, stripping out the leading #.
// hash is set to "hello-world"
var hash = $.param.fragment( "/index.php?a=1&b=2&c=3#hello-world" );
```