# Passing id through url to modal and update table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem, i was working on this for a few days and i am stuck. What i want to do? I want to pass $id through url to modal, witch opens on click and opens table with data that i can edit/update from mysql, using php! 
When i press edit i get data and person id in url but modal is not opening. I think my script/jquery is wrong, can someone look and help me.!!

When i press edit button i get this in url but nothing opens?!?!

```
http://localhost/zadatak_senso/index.php?poslovni_korisnici#update_poslovni=34
```

modal --> m_update_ok.php

```
<?php
// ---- Pocetak modal-a za update poslovnih korisnika ---- //
echo'
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="update_poslovni">  
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Uredi</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Unos poslovnih korisnika</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">';

      if (isset($_POST['submit_upk'])) {            

            $partnername    = $_POST['partner_name'];
            $partnerstreet  = $_POST['partner_street'];
            $partnerzip     = $_POST['partner_zip'];
            $partnercity    = $_POST['partner_city'];
            $partnercountry = $_POST['partner_country'];

            $sql = "UPDATE poslovni_partneri 
                     SET 
                     Partner_name     = '$partnername', 
                     Partner_street   = '$partnerstreet', 
                     Partner_zip      = '$partnerzip', 
                     Partner_city     = '$partnercity', 
                     Partner_country  = '$partnercountry' 
                     WHERE Partner_id = '$id'";

        // Prepare statement
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

        // execute the query
        $stmt->execute();

        }

        echo'
        <form method="POST" target="_parent" >
        <table id="table_id" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Partner name</th>
              <th>Partner street</th>
              <th>Partner zip</th>
              <th>Partner city</th>
              <th>Partner country</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>';

        $id = $_GET['Partner_id'];              

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM poslovni_partneri WHERE Partner_id LIKE '$id'";
        $stmt = $dbh->query($sql);
        $row =$stmt->fetchObject();

        $partner_name    = $row['partner_name'];
        $partner_street  = $row['partner_street'];
        $partner_zip     = $row['partner_zip'];
        $partner_city    = $row['partner_city'];
        $partner_country = $row['partner_country'];

        echo'
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="partner_name" value="'.$partner_name.'">'.$partnername.'</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="partner_street" value="'.$partner_street.'">'.$partnerstreet.'</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="partner_zip" value="'.$partner_zip.'">'.$partnerzip.'</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="partner_city" value="'.$partner_city.'">'.$partnercity.'</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="partner_country" value="'.$partner_country.'">'.$partnercountry.'</td>
        </tr> 
        </tbody>
      </table>


      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_upk" value="Uredi" />
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
<script>
    $(function(){

        $("a.update_poslovni").click(function(e) 
        {
            event.preventDefault(); // for the <a href="#" not to fire
            var bookId = $(this).data("book-id");
            $("#update_poslovni").find("input[name="bookId"]").val(bookId);
            $("#update_poslovni").dialog({modal: true});
        });

    });
</script>
</script>';
// ---- Kraj modal-a za update poslovnih korisnika ---- //
?>
```

index.php

```
echo'  <table id="table_id" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Partner name</th>
              <th>Partner street</th>
              <th>Partner zip</th>
              <th>Partner city</th>
              <th>Partner country</th>
              <th></th>
              <th><a href="edit.php?editPoslovni="><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Delete</button></a></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>';

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM poslovni_partneri";

        foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
        {

            echo'
            <tr>
                <td>'.$row['Partner_name'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Partner_street'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Partner_zip'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Partner_city'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Partner_country'].'</td>
                <td><a href="#update_poslovni='.$row['Partner_id'].'" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-id="'.$row['Partner_id'].'">Edit</a></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="blankCheckbox" value="option1" aria-label="..."></td>
            </tr>';
        }

        echo'    
        </tbody>
    </table>';
```

Comment: Don't you mean to use index.php?poslovni_korisnici&update_poslovni=34 ?

Comment: i guess so, im lost in code :P

Answer (score 0):

Get the hash from the URL: [How can you check for a #hash in a URL using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298503/how-can-you-check-for-a-hash-in-a-url-using-javascript)

Once you have the hash, simple get the element with the id selector of the hash and then:

```
$(hash).modal('show')
```

Comment: does not work, I have not managed to do that. can you make me a code for it