# How can I make something on the page change when the url contains #something

Tags: php, html

I've made it so when you click on a certain link it changes the url to mywebsite.com/page.php#certainusername

How can I make it so when the url contains someone's certain username, an object containing

```
data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=certainusername"
```

will change certain username to the username in #?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url) function. You should be able to get the fragment (hashmark thing) from that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of change you are talking about... So here are 3 different types of methods to access the "#certainusername"

### CSS

```
:target {
   background: yellow;
}
```

([Source](https://css-tricks.com/on-target/))

---

### PHP

```
parse_url($url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT)
// or
parse_url($url)['fragment']
// then do stuff ...
```

([Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php))

---

### JavaScript

```
window.location.hash
```

([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298503/how-can-you-check-for-a-hash-in-a-url-using-javascript))

Answer (score 0):

For the question, I assume that you're not working with any framework. Given this, I'll give you a simple answer.

Steps:

1 - Get the username out of the URL.

2 - Generate the view dynamically.

Explanation:

1 - I would recommend using a query string of the following format: mywebsite.com/page.php?username=certainusername (instead of using a #)
Then you can use $_GET to obtain the username (Please, read more about the security implications: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

2 - If you're using PHP to generate the HTML code directly, the only thing that you need to do is:

```
... HTML in here ...
data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=<?php echo $username; ?>"
... more HTML ...
```

(Assuming that the variable $username contains the username obtained from the URL).

This is a very simple scenario and there are a lot of other things to consider that are out of the scope of the question.