# Fire jquery trigger if page loads with #url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that contains tabs of information.
In some circumstances i need to open with a specific tab active, so i assigned a unique div and class to it and have #reviews appended to the url.
The page scrolls correctly to have the tabs in view, but I can't figure out how to open the tab ONLY when #reviews is in the url.

If i add

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".rTab").trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

to the div the tab opens on every page load.
So, is there a method of checking for a #url to fire the trigger() ?

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298503/how-can-you-check-for-a-hash-in-a-url-using-javascript

Comment: Thanks. I did search about, but obviously not using the right terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work depending on what you need..

Without jQuery

```
if(window.location.hash == '#hashurlhere'){
    var trigger = document.getElementsByClassName("rTab");
    trigger[0].click();
}
```

With

```
if(window.location.hash == '#urlhere'){
    jQuery(".rTab").trigger('click');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a[href=#reviews]").trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

```
   if(window.location.hash == $(this).attr('href')) $(this).trigger('click');
```

I found this code a while ago, credits to the author.

Comment: Woops mybad, I wrote the comment, searched for the code on my pc, and found this one, and I was like 'Hey, this suits better!' :p thanks for mentioning it.