# How to display something in HTML when #error is added at end of URL

Tags: php, html

This is my situation, I have a login page and in the functions folder there is the php for that, say the page is example.com/login.php, upon login error it redirects to example.com/login.php#error

Essentially I'm trying to figure out how to add code that only shows when you are on the #error page.

Comment: Instead of `example.com/login.php#error`, you should redirect the page to `example.com/login.php?error` so that you could catch the status using `$_GET` superglobal and display appropriate error message, kinda like this:  `if(isset($_GET['error'])){ /* display error message */ }`

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Thanks man, that works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

redirect with url like this:

> example.com/login.php?error=here_Message

then, use this code for get the message:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['error'])){
    echo $_GET['error'];
      }
?>
```

Comment: Works perfect thanks, I just made my url example.com/login.php?error and then used 

if(isset($_GET['error'])){
    echo "Login Failed";
      }

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're constrained in some way to use the hash (#error), you can use good old javascript.  I adapted the solution below from this old response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6682514/6525724

```
if(window.location.hash) {
  var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1); //Puts hash in variable, and removes the # character
  if(hash=="error") {  
    // Handle error
  }
}
```

Comment: Wasn't constrained, but rather uneducated in php, just a beginner. I ended up using ?error instead, but thank you for your response. Will keep it in mind if i'm ever constrained to a hash.