# How to block a link if its href contains a hash?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, events

if condition working but else condition not working.

```
 (function($){
   $(".single-product a").on("click", function(e){
     var link = $(".single-product a").attr("href");    
     if(link == "#"){
        e.preventDefault();
      }else{
        return true;
      }
   });

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: do you know how hash links work ??

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298503/how-can-you-check-for-a-hash-in-a-url-using-javascript

Comment: Hello! Please accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this? using prop on the attr it might be your jquery library is higher

```
$(document).on("click",".single-product a", function(e){
     var link = $.trim($(this).prop("href"));  
     (link == "#") ?  e.preventDefault() : '';
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

With the [attribute contains selector `[name*=”value”]`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```js
$('.single-product a[href*="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<div class="single-product">
  <a href="https://www.google.com#foo">With #</a>
</div>

<div class="single-product">
  <a href="https://www.google.com">Without #</a>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```