# jQuery (JavaScript): Knowing navigated ID on Document Load from different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I am working on a Bootstrap, jQuery project where I'm applying scrolling animations and functionality to the HTML.

When I am loading an HTML document, I want to know if the user navigated to "this" document with an ID or resource specified at the end of the URL, like so:

> http://domain.example/page#section

Essentially, I want to execute jQuery code *relatively* to whether somebody navigates to the document having specified no ID at the end of the URL, or having specified one. I would assume that if this is possible, it would be done in `$(document.ready())`.

I find this pretty easy to do if I'm navigating to a resource on the same page, but in this instance where I'm navigating from a *different page*, I'm stuck and I would really appreciate a response whether this is possible or not.

Comment: you can check `window.location.hash` for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is a relatively similar question to that of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298503/how-can-you-check-for-a-hash-in-a-url-using-javascript), of which [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/298513/2358222) describes a simple answer of checking whether or not a hash fragment exists:

```
if(window.location.hash) {
  // Fragment exists
} else {
  // Fragment doesn't exist
}
```

I realise, you may well want to check for **different** hash fragments, so I've added upon the answer to get this:

```
var hash = window.location.hash.replace('#','');
if(hash == "section") {
    // Fragment exists and is equal to section 
} else {
    // Fragment doesn't exist
}
```

This checks for a hash fragment in the URL, if it exists and is equal to #section the if statement returns true.