# Change a value in js code by using PHP GET method, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have a html file that have this javasscript code

```
var a=["","#"]
```

so i want to add a value after the # by writing that value in the website link

like :

> site.com/#value

so the js code will be

```
var a=["","#value"]
```

is that possible by using GET in php?

and how ?

Thank you

Comment: You can read the #value in javascript using `window.location.hash` . See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6682514/1512654

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in pure JS:

```
var a = ["", window.location.hash];
```

Comment: when i write site.com/test.html#value and check the `var a = ["", window.location.hash];
` in the chrome inspector
it didn't changed, why ?

Comment: i want to add the value in the html file

Comment: If you need to "print" the value in HTML, thats not possible, because the hash is not sent to the server. My answer only update the JS variable.

Comment: Make sure the url is loaded with the #value (press enter after typing it), then the code in chrome inspector should work