# How to get identical URLs when onClick functions show/hide different content on same webpage?

Tags: jquery

I have click functions in jQuery to show/hide different content:

```
$(“#button1”).click(function() {
  $(“#project1”)[0].style.display = "block";
  $(“#project2”)[0].style.display = “none”;
});

$(“#button2”).click(function() {
  $(“#project1”)[0].style.display = “none”;
  $(“#project2”)[0].style.display = “block”;
});
```

I want to have an identical URL in each situation. For example when `#project1` is shown I want the URL in the webpage different than the URL when `#project2` is shown.

Now it is always `https://…./..../projects/index.html`

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window.location.hash` to add a fragment to the URL.

In addition, if you're using jQuery to select elements and add event handlers, you may as well use it to show/hide content too. Also note that the quotes you're using are not valid JS. Only `"` and `'` is allowed. Try this:

```js
$("#button1").click(function() {
  $("#project1").show()
  $("#project2").hide();
  window.location.hash = 'project1';
});

$("#button2").click(function() {
  $("#project1").hide();
  $("#project2").show();
  window.location.hash = 'project2';
});
```

Comment: It works, thank you! But then I wonder: if I refresh the URL "https://…./..../projects/index.html#project1", how it can show #project1 without clicking the button..?

Comment: You need to write the code for that to happen. You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6682514/519413) to detect the fragment. Then you just need to show/hide the relevant elements