# javascript get from link or check #section2 element

Tags: javascript, url, href

**Hello**
How do I get a link using javascript, which is set using href = "#"

Scroll section 2

How get from link - #section2
https://example.com/page.html#section2

Thanks for help

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298503/how-can-you-check-for-a-hash-in-a-url-using-javascript. and getting the link using javascript should be easy.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your problem like how do you want it to get executed. Do you want to get the link using url or on click on the same page, or something else.