# jump link in iframe from reveal js

Tags: html, iframe, reveal.js

I would like this to be integrated into my internal page via iframe in revealjs

`<section id="xx" data-background-iframe="xx.html" data-background-interactive></section>`

The jump link in xx.html

`<a href="/xa">jump link</a>`

Insert that I can call them something like this
`https://www.xx/#/xx/xa`

Comment: Okay, if I don't misinterpret your question, do you want the iframe to load a specific page if the URL is `https://www.xx/#/xx/xa`?

Comment: The id"xx" in the iframe loads `https://www.xx/#/xx`  and the jump link xa should load `https://www.xx/#/xx/xa` to a specific area in the page. The anchor is a jump link, but I read in a url that I can't have two anchors, `/#/xx/#/xa` or is that possible?

Comment: Yes, you cannot have two Location Hash (the hash path) in the same URL. You can [use JavaScript to obtain the location hash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/298513/188331) and ask the iframe to load the corresponding URL.