# Show checkbox value in URL

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have a page that makes a query with Ajax. Checkboxes on this page work without any URL. What I want to do is to be able to load this data with URL. So when I enter a value in the url, I want that data to come automatically.

```js
$checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox');
$checkboxes.change(function(){
    window.location.hash = 'marka=' + $checkboxes.filter(':checked').map(function(){
        return this.value;   
    }).get().join(",");
    console.log(window.location.hash);
});
```

```html
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
 <input class="custom-control-input common_selector marka" type="checkbox" id="marka_1" value="1">
 <label class="custom-control-label cz-filter-item-text" for="marka_1">Value 1 </label>
 <input class="custom-control-input common_selector marka" type="checkbox" id="marka_2" value="2">
 <label class="custom-control-label cz-filter-item-text" for="marka_21">Value 2 </label>
 <input class="custom-control-input common_selector marka" type="checkbox" id="marka_3" value="3">
 <label class="custom-control-label cz-filter-item-text" for="marka_3">Value 3 </label>
 <input class="custom-control-input common_selector marka" type="checkbox" id="marka_4" value="4">
 <label class="custom-control-label cz-filter-item-text" for="marka_4">Value 4 </label>
  </div>
```

I want to load data via URL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you check for a #hash in a URL using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298503/how-can-you-check-for-a-hash-in-a-url-using-javascript)

Comment: Sorry, this is not exactly the answer I was looking for

Comment: Are you saying, you want to pass the checked values for the checkbox via url like http://url.com?marka=1&marka=2&marka=4 and get those checkboxes checked on page load?

Comment: So then what kind of answer you are looking for? Read hash value and set your input value depending on that

Comment: @Extreme_Tough Definitely yes It would be great for me to just bring a 1 checkbox url.com?marka=1 or 2 or 3

Comment: The question is unclear.  Changing the hash of the current page will not trigger data to download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to both save checkbox state to the hash, and then load it again when someone visits a URL with checkbox info in the hash.

You already have the code which saves the checkbox state to the hash.  You're using a simple comma-separted list like `#marka=2,4`.  Loading that data back is simple enough:

- read the hash with `window.location.hash`;
- remove the `#`;
- remove `marka=` so you are left only with the `value`s of the checked checkboxes;
- create an array of the values left;
- iterate over all checkboxes and check those whose values are in that array;

Something like this:

```
function loadCheckboxState() {
    // Get the hash, and remove the '#', we are left with marka=2,4
    let string = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    // Remove 'marka=', so we are left with 2,4
    string.replace('marka=', '');

    // Create an array of the ids left, [2,4]
    let checked = string.split(',');

    // Now check the checkboxes whose value is in the array
    $checkboxes.prop('checked', function () {
        return checked.indexOf(this.value) >= 0;
    });
}
```

You could run it on page load, eg:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    loadCheckboxState();
});
```

Note there are a few minor issues in your code:

- jQuery 1.9.1 is ancient (2013!), you should be using a more recent version;
- Typo: `$('input[type=checkbox')`;
- Typo: `for="marka_21"`;
- [Use `var`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-should-i-use-it-or-omit-it) ([or `let`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-var)) to declare your variables;

#### Update

Add code as a runnable snippet - note it doesn't work here due to the way Stackoverflow snippets are embeded.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Load checkbox state from hash on page load
    loadCheckboxState();

    // When a checkbox is changed, update the hash
    $checkboxes.change(saveCheckboxState);    
});

let $checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]');
let $link = $('#link');
let SOurl = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74428447/show-checkbox-value-in-url';

// This will save checkbox state in the hash
function saveCheckboxState() {
    window.location.hash = 'marka=' + $checkboxes.filter(':checked').map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get().join(",");

    // Just for debugging, show it on the page
    let link = SOurl + window.location.hash;
    $link.attr('href', link).html(link);
}

function loadCheckboxState() {
    // Get the hash, and remove the '#', we are left with marka=2,4
    let string = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    // Remove 'marka=', so we are left with 2,4
    string.replace('marka=', '');

    // Create an array of the ids left, [2,4]
    let checked = string.split(',');

    // Now check the checkboxes whose value is in the array
    $checkboxes.prop('checked', function () {
        return checked.indexOf(this.value) >= 0;
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="">
    <input class="" type="checkbox" id="marka_1" value="1">
    <label class="" for="marka_1">Value 1 </label>
    <input class="" type="checkbox" id="marka_2" value="2">
    <label class="" for="marka_2">Value 2 </label>
    <input class="" type="checkbox" id="marka_3" value="3">
    <label class="" for="marka_3">Value 3 </label>
    <input class="" type="checkbox" id="marka_4" value="4">
    <label class="" for="marka_4">Value 4 </label>
</div>

<p>Generated link: <a id="link"></a>
```

Comment: Can u post the code like i sent at snippet. I want to see it live. I can't figure it out.

Comment: @Avza I've added it but because of the way Stackoverflow embeds snippets as iframes, and that they don't run on page load, it doens't work here ... what is the problem?

Comment: hi Hello, first of all thank you for your help. Unfortunately it won't load when I try this.  [link] (https://dermoevim.com/kategori/anne-bebek/emzirme-urunleri#marka=30) example

Comment: I get many errors on the browser devtools console on that page, eg `product.js?revision=7.2.3.2-10-1665068254:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'product')`, `product.js?revision=7.2.3.2-10:18 Uncaught ReferenceError: anticsrf is not defined`, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'innerHTML')` and more ...

Comment: Hi @Don't Panic, You may not pay attention to them :)